# Why am getting an error when authenticating a password token in the following PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get my php authentication to work on the following program.  My tokens are not matching up and I can't figure out why.  I've confirmed that the correct is field is being called in mysql database but I keep getting denied access because the tokens are not the same.  Any help/insight is appreciated.

```
<?php // 
require_once 'dlogin.php';
$connection = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])    &&
    isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
{
    $un_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    $pw_temp = mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);

    $query  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un_temp'";
    $result = $connection->query($query);
    if (!$result) die ($connection->error);
    elseif ($result->num_rows)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

          $result->close();

          $salt1 = "qm&h*";
          $salt2 = "pg!@";
          $token = hash('ripemd128', "$salt1$pw_temp$salt2");

          if ($token == $row[3]) echo "$row[0] $row[1] : Hi $row[0], you are now logged in as '$row[2]'";
            else die("Invalid username/password combination, token");
    }
      else die("Invalid username/password combination");
}
else
{
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Section"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    die ("Please enter your name and password");
}

$connection->close();

function mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $string)
{
    return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($connection, $string));
}

function mysql_fix_string($connection, $string)
{
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);
    return $connection->real_escape_string($string);
}
?>
```

Comment: seems you're closing `$result->close();` too soon, I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

Well try this

```
$token = hash('ripemd128', "$salt1$pw_temp$salt2");
echo "NEW TOKEN: "+$token
echo '<br>';
echo "STRING: $salt1$pw_temp$salt2";
echo '<br>';
echo "DB Token: "+$row[3];
```

now either place the new token output in the database or try re-hashing the string using an reliable source and check the differences.